# Structure of Ring adjoint with $\frac{1}{f}$, where $f \in R$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am studying commutative algebra from Atiyah and Macdonald and I just ran into a ring of the form $R[\frac{1}{f}]$ where $f \in R, f \neq 0$.

What exactly is this ring? I am a bit confused because it is definitely not necessary for $f$ to be a unit, also in the context, I ran into it (explained below), doesn't make me think that it's a ring of polynomials over $R$ with indeterminate $\frac{1}{f}$.

For context (I don't need help on this, I am sure I will be able to prove this once I know what $R[\frac{1}{f}]$ looks like): Spec$R[\frac{1}{f}] \to$ Spec$(R)$ is a homeomorphism onto its image.

Comment: It's a special case of localization, where you use $S := \{ f^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ as the multiplicative set in $S^{-1} R$.

Comment: That's all I needed, just couldn't find it anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: ... or $R[X]/(fX-1)$

Comment: Right, my formulation and Hagen von Eitzen's are canonically isomorphic.  And also, they're both initial objects in the category of $R$-algebras in which (the image of) $f$ is a unit.